# Integer ops only 3D triangle-triangle collision detection

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, computational-geometry

I've a need for 3D triangle-triangle collision detection using integer math only. Unfortunately, I'm not in a position where I can use 64-bit integers (only 32-bit) and my vertex values can be larger than 24-bit values. This makes overflows a tricky problem -- otherwise I could probably just use fixed point operations.

The good news is I don't need perfect accuracy -- after all, we're using integers. Additionally, it does not need to be continuous collision detection -- the velocities will be zero. But I may have large triangles tested for collision with small triangles, so coarse approximations of normals can lead to gross relative errors.

The triangles themselves are represented as triplets of 32-bit integer vectors.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Cross-posted to [GameDevelopment](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/108033/13295).

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by several uses of computing the signed volume of tetrahedra. I described the idea in this MSE posting: "[Find whether two triangles intersect or not in 3D](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58410/237)."

Then your problem is reduced to ensuring that the cubic volume computation
doesn't overflow. You could detect overflow and only resort to floating-point computations when necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't rely on floating point, even as a fall-through. It's not solely a matter of performance -- it's a matter of cross-platform repeatability. Because of this, computing the intersection between a line segment and a triangle is also nontrivial -- how to do it with integer math without overflowing doesn't seem straightforward. I suspect I may need to use a fixed point representation or emulate floating point calculations to guarantee repeatability if a more direct method doesn't exist.

Comment: @Kaganar: I think you need to simulate more bits. There's no magic solution. Essentially you need to be able to accurately compute *a b c*, where *a,b,c* are coordinates. You might have to write multiple-word add and multiply functions, essentially a limited bignum package.

Comment: There's some more "creative" solutions I've thought of such as tessellating the triangles on the fly in directions of convergence, but that would converge too slowly to be reasonably performant in some cases. I think you've talked me into writing my own repeatable number handling routines -- thanks!

Comment: @Kaganar: Good luck! I don't envy you. Don't reinvent the wheel: [Gnu bignum](https://gmplib.org/) etc.

Answer (score 1):

What about an axis-parallel bounding box test (which you probably perform anyway), with a recursive subdivision of the triangles in case of doubt ? (A triangle can be split in four sub-triangles by taking the midpoints of the edges).

A much tighter bounding will be achieved with additional planes, based on the evaluation of the max of ±x±y, ±x±y±z and the like (26 directions in total).

Just integer additions and halvings.

Comment: This is a fantastic idea, one which I had considered -- my main issue is how it deals with coplanar triangles with small separation. There could be an exponential explosion of interfering bounding boxes. Is there a way around this I perhaps haven't considered?

Comment: I wonder if exponential explosion can really manifest itself, given the pruning that will take place. Termination of the splitting process is also an open question, as you may not be sure that the triangles do intersect just by looking at the bounding boxes. Anyway, after a sufficient number of subdivisions, the range of the coordinates becomes smaller and smaller, so that overflow-free computation becomes feasible again.

Comment: Just for kicks I hobbled together a pruning version of this and ran it on two triangles where v = 2000 and s = 10: ([0, 0, 0], [v, v, 0], [0, v, v]) and ([0, s, 0], [v, v + s, 0], [0, v + s, v]). Note these are the same triangle, just one is shifted up by 10 units. It took about ten million calls to confirm that they do not intersect. For each each 10 added to s, this goes down fairly quickly.. s = 20 results in 2.5 million, s = 30 results in 1.3 million, s = 40 results in .5 million, and so on...

Comment: Mh, a little too much :( Do you split both triangles every time ?